# Return text between two special characters (vertical bar)

Tags: macos, excel-formula

I'm trying to extract the text between two special characters (vertical bar). It works for me for other special characters but not when trying with the vertical bar.

This works:

```
FIRST | SECOND < THIRD > END

=MID(A1,SEARCH(CHAR(60),A1)+2,SEARCH(CHAR(62),A1)-SEARCH(CHAR(60),A1)-2)
```

This doesn't work:

```
FIRST | SECOND < THIRD | END

=MID(A1,SEARCH(CHAR(60),A1)+2,SEARCH(CHAR(124),A1)-SEARCH(CHAR(60),A1)-2)
```

Expected result:

```
THIRD
```

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: It works for me as well. But I would suggest a more clear formula `=MID(LEFT(A1, FIND("|", A1) - 2), FIND("<", A1) + 2, LEN(A1))`. `2` because of the spaces between the deliminators in your examples. You also don't need to lookup by char index.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I noticed that the issue seems to be the preceding "|" character. I have updated my question above. Since the text I will use the formula on will contain multiple special characters.

Comment: does this work for your cases: `=LEFT(REPLACE(A1,1,FIND("<",A1)+1,""),FIND("|",REPLACE(A1,1,FIND("<",A1)+1,""))-2)`

Comment: That did the trick, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=LEFT(REPLACE(A1,1,FIND("<",A1)+1,""),FIND("|",REPLACE(A1,1,FIND("<",A1)+1,""))-2)
```

[image]